# iPhone Keyboard Next Button

Tags: iphone, button, iphone-softkeyboard

How do I use the next button (the done button) in the bottom left of the keyboard on the iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if i understand the question.

[Here](http://www.flexicoder.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/iphone-keyboard-automatically-move-to-next-textfield-when-next-is-pressed/) is solution

---

Code snippit from link:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == field1TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [field2TextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
    else if (textField == field2TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [field3TextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == field3TextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: To those who sees this, remember that the -(BOOL) method is used when you create the UITextField programatically. If you have created the TextField from the Library, you would want to create an `-(IBAction)` for the TextFields. When linking the actions to the respective TextField, choose `Did End On Exit` and everything else just copy from the website.